# Repair a 220V PCB trace

Tags: pcb, repair

I had a water issue with a PCB power strip that has a PCB inside. About half the width of the 220Volt traces got connected and burned so "luckyily" nothing else broke as the fault stopped there.

The traces are about 1cm wide each, but half the width about 5mm is burned off. Is it possible to fill the burned off lead of those traces or what is the best way to repair them as its quite high voltage I dont feel comfortable running them half width.

Comment: Bodge a decent gauge wire across the burned portions.

Comment: Do you know the current? Sounds like it could be quite a lot if they are 1cm wide.

Comment: An 18AWG wire is rated for more current than a 10mm wide PCB trace.  [This calculator](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/) will give the the current carrying capacity of PCB trace.

Answer (score -2):

The fault was lack of water protected insulation that caused a corona action burning the copper.  Obviously not designed for use near water.  A solid wire conductor and a silicone or other suitable coating of insulation is best . The power strip may have had an arc current just below the strip’s breaker rating or didn’t have one.  Buyer/Designer beware.  This design is unsafe without either suitable coating or an air gap of >= 4 mm between conductors.

Comment: -1 to newbie who cannot articulate his issue